# 2nd 'Element not interactable exception' when iterating on the loop, SELENIUM PYTHON

Tags: python, selenium, loops, element, visible

### Selenium does see displayed element visible on the page on the second iteration.

I click on a link, and a box within a website appears. I need to close that box.

This action will be performed 1000+ times. On the first iteration, Selenium opens the link and closes the box. On the second iteration, Selenium opens the link, and cannot close the box. At this point, it gives error message:

`Exception has occurred: ElementNotInteractableException Message: element not interactable (Session info: chrome=105.0.5195.102)`

My code + HTML of relevant element below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By    
import time

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r"D:\SeleniumDriver\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get('https://sprawozdaniaopp.niw.gov.pl/') 

find_button = driver.find_element("id", "btnsearch")

find_button.click()

interesting_links = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, "dialog")

for i in range(len(interesting_links)):

    interesting_links[i].click()
    time.sleep(10)                           # I tried 60 seconds, no change

    #
    #   HERE I WOULD DO MY THINGS
    #

    close_box = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-dialog-titlebar-close")
            
    print(close_box.is_displayed())
    close_box.click()                        # Here is where the program crushes on the 2nd iteration

    if i == 4:                               # Stop the program after 5 iterations
        break
```

HTML code of the relevant element:

```html
<a href="#" class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span></a>
```

I tried to locate the element that closes the box by CSS SELECTOR AND XPATH.

- The CSS SELECTOR of the X/close button is the same every time, but
  only the first time Selenium will see the X button displayed.
- THE XPATH is strange. On the first opening of the link, X/close button will have path:

> /html/body/div[6]/div[1]/a

However, if you open the next link, path will look this:

> /html/body/div[8]/div[1]/a

Let me know what you think of that :-)

Comment: Right now clicking any of the "interesting links" is going to a 404 page, not sure if/when that's fixed.

Comment: Hi @C.Peck - I also get that, if you click to fast on the link 404 will show up. Please let the page fully load and then click on one of the interesting links. I think waiting 15 seconds after you hit the "Znajdź" button is safe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one way to achieve your goal:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import time as t

chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument('disable-notifications')

chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1280,720")

webdriver_service = Service("chromedriver/chromedriver") ## path to where you saved chromedriver binary
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 20)
url = 'https://sprawozdaniaopp.niw.gov.pl/'
browser.get(url)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "btnsearch"))).click()
links = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class='dialog']")))
counter = 0
for link in links[:5]:
    link.click()
    print('clicked link', link.text)
    ### do your stuff ###
    t.sleep(1)
    wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"]')))[counter].click()
    print('closed the popup')
    counter = counter+1
```

This will print out in terminal:

```
clicked link STOWARZYSZENIE POMOCY DZIECIOM Z PORAŻENIEM MÓZGOWYM "JASNY CEL"
closed the popup
clicked link FUNDACJA NA RZECZ POMOCY DZIECIOM Z GRODZIEŃSZCZYZNY
closed the popup
clicked link FUNDACJA "ADAMA"
closed the popup
clicked link KUJAWSKO-POMORSKI ZWIĄZEK LEKKIEJ ATLETYKI
closed the popup
clicked link "RYBNICKI KLUB PIŁKARSKI - SZKÓŁKA PIŁKARSKA ROW W RYBNIKU"
closed the popup
```

Every time you click on a link, a new popup is created. When you close it, that popup will not disappear, but it will stay hidden. So when you click on a new link and then you want to close the new popup, you need to select the new (nth) close button. This should also apply to popup elements, so make sure you account for it. I stopped after the 5th link, of course you will need to remove the slicing to handle all links present in page.
Selenium setup above is chromedriver on linux - you just have to observe the imports, and the code after defining the browser(driver).

Selenium documentation can be found at https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/

Comment: Thank you Barry the Platipus, this solved my problem. :-)

I will look into Selenium documentation for more info - I get why I need to close the new popup, but not really. Unless when I locate 'span[class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"]' I get as many popup elements as links, and I need to hit the 'nth' close button too. That would make sense then.

And real thanks for introducing me to wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located)!

Comment: Thank you @KacperOleszkiewicz, glad I solved your issue. You probably need to close the popup after doing stuff with data from it, to make sure the next link is clickable. And when you click the `X` to close the pop-up, that `X` element doesn't disappear into thin air, instead remains invisible in page structure.